# How to hide posts from specific users?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hide, posts

I've been looking for a plugin but I think there is none for this specific need. What I want to do, is hide certain posts from certain users.

I've found plugins that only hide the content in the post from the user, but the user still can see the post in the index and archive pages. I need the post completely hidden from the user or users I select.

Doesn anyone know a plugin or what files and where to modify? I'm a beginner in php.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://wordpress.org/plugins/press-permit-core/
It offers a very granular control for content permissions.